# Avoid wrapping the object type name from input/output JSON (CXF Web Service)

Tags: json, cxf

I have a CXF Web Service something like this:

```
@Service("MyWebService")
public class MyWebService implements IMyWebService {    
    @Autowired
    private IMyService MyService;

    public ResponseObject doSomething(RequestObject requestObject) {
        ResponseObject responseObject = new ResponseObject;     
        .
        // do something....
        .
        .        
        return responseObject;
    }
}
```

that expects an input JSON, say something like this:

```
{ "requestObject" : { "amount" : 12.50, "userName" : "abcd123" } }
```

and produces an output JSON something like this:

```
{ "responseObject" : { "success" : "true", "errorCode" : 0 } }
```

Is there a way to configure CXF such that it accepts the input JSON in the following format:

```
{ "amount" : 12.50, "userName" : "abcd123" }
```

I need to strip out the object type name 'requestObject' / 'responseObject' in the input and output JSON. Is that even possible?

Your help appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

If you are using maven, the JSONProvider class is here:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

You might need another json provider properties to achieve your goals:

```
<jaxrs:providers>
     <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider">
           <property name="dropRootElement" value="true"/>
           <property name="dropCollectionWrapperElement" value="true"/>
           <property name="serializeAsArray" value="true"/>
           <property name="supportUnwrapped" value="true"/>
     </bean>
</jaxrs:providers>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are configuring the json provider through springs xml config file (like applicationContext.xml), then just add the below configuration it will work.

```
<jaxrs:providers>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider">
                <property name="dropRootElement" value="true" />
                <property name="supportUnwrapped" value="true" />
            </bean>
</jaxrs:providers>
```

The dropRootElement tells the json provider to drop the root element.  Refer to this [JSON Support](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CXF20DOC/JAX-RS+Data+Bindings#JAX-RSDataBindings-JSONsupport) for more configuration and understanding.

Comment: whats is your cxf version?? and what all the errors that you are getting ?

Comment: I am using 2.4.6, and I dont get errors. I just dont need the wrapper name as in { "requestObject" : { "amount" : 12.50, "userName" : "abcd123" } } instead I need the service to accept the JSON input without the wrapper name as in { "amount" : 12.50, "userName" : "abcd123" }. Actually RESTEasy does that.

Comment: every framework does it, i am using cxf 2.6.0 i dont know if that configuration is there for 2.4.6 .. check out the link that i have posted in my answer it contains info for that.. also be sure that you are configuring your json provider correctly

Comment: I get a ClassNotFoundException for org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider. Couldn't find it even on JarFinder.com.

Comment: Oh, this is because this package is introduced in 2.6 version you should use  org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JSONProvider

Comment: Tried the 2.6 version of CXF. Getting the following error at runtime, although the referred class is there: 

ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/exchange]] Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

Comment: you are missing the jars for springframework.. thats what it means.